# How do I fix a UnexpectedToken Error? Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently creating a Discord Bot. However, I cannot test my bot due to the Unexpected Token Error on the `require(./handler/${handler})(client);` line. How can I fix this?

````
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();

config({
  path: _dirname + "/.env"
})

["command"].forEach(handler => {
  require(./handler/${handler})(client);
});

//ON-READY FUNCTIONS

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: "online",
    game: {
      name: 'Axi's Palaciego | Prefix: *',
      type: "WATCHING"
    }
  });
});```
````

Comment: `require(./handler/${handler})` is a fairly obvious syntax error. The parameter to `require()` should be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo. `Unexpected Token Error` occurs when specific language construct was expected, but something else was provided. In order to use string interpolation use back ticks `` ` ` `` 
try 
`` require(`./handler/${handler}`)(client) ; ``

Comment: It works! Thanks for noticing!